# Read specific content of POM xml file through groovy xmlSurper and download dependecy

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing

I have a below POM file.I want to use xmlSlurper groovy code to read the specific content of the POM file Can someone tell me how to write the code to read the specific content through groovy xmlSlurper.I want to read the groupid artifact id,classifier and type of those whose scope is runtime in below POM file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ss.engine</groupId>
  <artifactId>nti</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0.110</version>
  <description>Configuration Management Gradle Plugin</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ss.engine</groupId>
      <artifactId>License</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0.5000</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.as.engine</groupId>
      <artifactId>commoncore</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0.100</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.as.engine</groupId>
      <artifactId>ncdes</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0.97</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.as.enginee</groupId>
      <artifactId>kgfhs</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0.137</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.operasolutions</groupId>
      <artifactId>Risk</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
      <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jamonapi</groupId>
      <artifactId>jamon</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
  <groupId>com.as.engine</groupId>
  <artifactId>les</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.3</version>
  <type>zip</type>
  <classifier>linux</classifier>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
      <version>1.10</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>args4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>args4j</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.28</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
      <artifactId>super-csv-dozer</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the script which I am using to read the contents of POM file and download the dependency whose scope is runtime from the artifactory.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

// ------ Tell the script to get dependencies from artifactory ------
    repositories {
         maven {
        url "http://abc.de.fg:80/artifactory/fes-release-local"
              }
        }

    buildscript {
    repositories {
      maven {
        url "http://abc.de.fg:80/artifactory/libs-snapshot"
         }
    }
    // ------ Tell the script to get dependencies from artifactory ------
    dependencies {
    classpath ([ "cop.trn.cm:cmugin:1.2.147" ])
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.uven.eplugin'

/**
 * The folloing -D parameters are required to run this task
 *  - deployLayer = one of acceptance, latest, production, test
 */
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Read the properties file and take the value as per the environment.
// 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if(!System.properties.deployLayer) throw new Exception ("deployLayer must be set")
def thePropFile = file("config/${System.properties.deployLayer}.properties")
if(!thePropFile.exists()) throw new Exception("Cannot load the specified environment properties from ${thePropFile}")
println "Deploying ${System.properties.jobName}.${System.properties.buildNumber} to ${System.properties.deployLayer}"

// load the deploy properties from the file
def deployProperties = new Properties()
thePropFile.withInputStream { 
    stream -> deployProperties.load(stream) 
} 
// set them in the build environment
project.ext {
  deployProps = deployProperties
  deployRoot = deployProperties["${System.properties.jobName}.deployroot"]
  deploydir = deployProperties["${System.properties.jobName}.deploydir"]
  deployFolder = deployProperties["${System.properties.jobName}.foldername"]
  deployPostInstallSteps = deployProperties["${System.properties.jobName}.postInstallSteps"]
}

task deleteGraphicsAssets(type: Delete, dependsOn: deploy) {
    def dirName = "${deployRoot}"
    delete dirName

    doLast {
        file(dirName).mkdirs()
    }
}

task downloaddependecies(dependsOn: deleteGraphicsAssets) << {
  def pomFile = file("${buildDir}/artifacts").listFiles().find { it.name.endsWith 'pom' }
  def pomXml = new XmlSlurper().parse(pomFile.absolutePath)
  def pomDependencies = pomXml.dependencies.dependency
  Configuration configuration = project.configurations.detachedConfiguration()
  configuration.transitive = false
  pomDependencies.each { dependency ->
    if(dependency.scope == 'runtime') {
    def dependencySpec = dependencies.create("${dependency.groupId}:${dependency.artifactId}:${dependency.version}:${dependency.classifier}@${dependency.type}")
      println "Found Runtime Dependency: ${dependencySpec}"
      configuration.dependencies.add(dependencySpec)
                  }
                }
                println "RESOLVED THE FOLLOWING"
                configuration.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies.each { println it }
                copy {
                  from configuration
    into ( "${buildDir}/artifacts" )
                }
}


task copyartifactZip << {
    copy {
        from "${deployRoot}"
        into "${deploydir}/"
    }
}

task copyLicenseZip << {
    copy {
        from "${deployRoot}"
        into "${deploydir}/${deployFolder}"
    }
}

task myCustomTask(dependsOn: downloaddependecies) << {
    copy {
        from 'deploymentfiles'
        into "${deployRoot}"
    }
}
task unzipArtifact(dependsOn: myCustomTask) << {
  def theZip = file("${buildDir}/artifacts").listFiles().find { it.name.endsWith('.zip') }
  println "Unzipping ${theZip} the artifact to: ${deployRoot}"
  ant.unzip(src: theZip, dest: "${deployRoot}", overwrite: true)
}

task setPerms(type:Exec, dependsOn: unzipArtifact) {
  workingDir "${deployRoot}"
  executable "bash"
  args "-c", "chmod -fR 755 *"

  }
def dirName = "${deploydir}/${deployFolder}"
task zipDeployment(type: GradleBuild, dependsOn: setPerms) { GradleBuild gBuild ->
    def env = System.getenv()
    def jobName=env['jobName']
if (jobName.equals("LicenseGenerator")) {
    delete dirName
    file(dirName).mkdirs()
    gBuild.tasks = ['copyLicenseZip']
    } else {
   gBuild.tasks = ['copyartifactZip']
}
}

task deployAll(dependsOn: zipDeployment){}
```